# How can I remove a function that has been added to wordpress with add_filter?

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, filters

to begin with I am trying to modify a wordpress plugin.

I have created a function named `fuxia_is_the_best`. Then I add this function to the `sanitize_title` filter, with the use of this code:

```
add_filter('sanitize_title', 'fuxia_is_the_best');
```

and this `add_filter` function goes inside an if statement:

```
if ( $lama == 'green' ) {
  add_filter('sanitize_title', 'fuxia_is_the_best');
} else {
  remove_filter('sanitize_title', 'fuxia_is_the_best');
}
```

If you noticed I have an else statement in which I'm using the `remove_filter()` function.
But there goes my problem and the cause of this question in general. The `remove_filter()` 
doesn't actually `remove` the `filter` :/ .

**Question**:

- What could have gone wrong?
- Is there anything wrong in this php code above?

*closure*:
Thanks in advance for your time, you're awesome!

Comment: Difficult tot say without more context. Could be a timing problem: the filter is removed after it has been executed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.